# mmap of 4k * 4K floats leading to segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, mmap

I'm reading matrix of floats from file. Dimensions of matrix are 4k * 4K. With the below program, it just leads to reset in now() function strangely. if I reduce the matrix size to 1k * 1K, it doesn't reset. Though it reads floats correctly but last few values are junk. I don't know where these junk values are coming from. I took the size of BUFFSIZE 6 since it digits in the floating number is going to be around 5-6. Not sure if it is correct.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>


#define ROWS 4000
#define COLS 4000
#define BUFFSIZE 6

//#define USE_FREAD
#define USE_MMAP

double now()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec / 1000000.;
}

int main()
{

    double end_time;
    double total_time;
    int i, x, y, k;
    for (k = 0; k < 1; k++)
    {
    double start_time = now();

    FILE* in = fopen("resistence_file", "rb");

    float arr[ROWS][COLS];

    char temp[BUFFSIZE];

    int val;
    std::stringstream ss;
    char* floats  = (char*)mmap(

            0,

            ROWS * COLS * sizeof(float),

            PROT_READ,

            MAP_FILE | MAP_PRIVATE,

            fileno(in),

            0

            );

    fclose(in);
    ss<<floats;

    for (int i =0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            if ((ss.getline(temp, BUFFSIZE, ' ')) )
            {
                arr[i][j] = atof((temp));
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i =0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            printf("%.1f ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    munmap(floats, ROWS * COLS * sizeof(float));


    end_time = now();
    total_time = end_time - start_time;

    printf("It took %f seconds to read %d * %d matrix \n", total_time, ROWS, COLS);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Splitting functions apart onto multiple lines is done to improve readability.  Do you really think your `mmap` call is more readable written that way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`float arr[4000][4000];` will require 56Mb (assuming `sizeof(float)=4`).  This is very likely to be larger than your available stack.

You'll need to either move `arr` to have static duration

```
static float arr[ROWS][COLS];
...
int main()
```

or allocate it dynamically, remembering to `free` it later

```
int main()
{
    float (*arr)[COLS] = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * ROWS);
    ....
    free(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks, It did not lead to segfault when I allocated arr on dynamic memory. But I still see 0.0 values in the last for several hundred floats. Can you suggest why it could be ???

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

Comment: I'm not sure but would guess that `ss.getline` sometimes fails.  You could add logging to check for this.

Comment: It seems mmap is never mapping the entire matrix. If it is of size 4K *4k in file, it gives the mapped string with data up to 3.5K * 3.5K. But if I reduce the size in file up to 3k * 3K, mapped string is still deprecated with incomplete data. I don't know what is the problem. I see junk characters at the end of mapped string

Comment: ok it worked after I changed float to double. Can somebody please explain why it worked ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You are mapping a file of `sizeof(float)*K` bytes as if it contained binary data. If it contains known amount of binary floating point data, why are you trying to work with later it as if it contained text? If it contains text, what does it have to do with `sizeof(float)`? Are you absolutely sure your floating-point numbers occupy, *as text*, `sizeof(float)` bytes on the average, including the space delimiter? That's about 3 non-blank characters per number at most places.
2. You are feeding `ss` a string which may or may not be NUL-terminated.

Not directly related to the crash: this whole business of `stringstream` and `getline` here is a complete waste of spacetime (OK at least a waste of 64 megabytes of space and of at least some time). Not speaking of `atof` which no programmer should ever touch with a six feet long pole. I hope you don't seriously plan to do that in production code. Just use `std::strtod` on the original array in place of all this.

Comment: I have an file which contains floats (4k * 4k). I receive it from third party. I need to extract floats from this file and store it in matrix and do linear equation algo on the matrix. If I try to map it as float pointer, it doesn't give me any meaningful data but if I map it as text, it gives me values. I agree with what you said. But how would I know, what should be the buffer size in mmap function since all I know is it's a file containing 4k * 4K floats.

Comment: If you don't know how to determine the size of the file, you ask a question. "How to determine the size of a file in C++?" would be a reasonably good start. Try googling it.